# Are Power BI workspaces and app workspaces the same thing?

Tags: powerbi

I'm a little confused about the concept of an Power BI workspace vs. an app workspace. They sound like the same thing but it seems that security is handled differently with each. For example, it seems that with workspaces, Azure Active Directory security groups can be used to control user access. But with app workspaces, this isn't possible. But, it could be I'm reading this incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Microsoft documentation covers this fairly well:

- [Power BI apps FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-create-the-new-workspaces#power-bi-apps-faq)

Basically, the new workspaces aren't tied to Office 365 groups but rather allow for more flexible assigning of roles (including Active Directory security groups, distribution lists, and Office 365 groups) and more granular permissions management of roles (admins, members, contributors).

Eventually, the current app workspaces will be phased out and migrated to the new workspaces (which are currently in the preview phase).

Comment: Thank you. This is useful. Can you tell me what happens when content is published to production. Does production content also sit within the workspace.concept?

Comment: The workspaces are for collaborating to create and publish apps (consisting of reports and dashboards). The apps are permissioned separately when you go to publish or update them and you can make them available to the entire organization or whatever set of individuals and groups you specify (independent of the workspace permissions).

Comment: So anything you publish is published as an app, whether it's a single report or 100?

Comment: Yeah. I have some that are one report and others that have lots. It's however you decide to group reports.

Comment: So, Now can we use Azure AD groups to manage access to workspaces in power BI. If yes, can you provide a reference link for documentation?

Answer (score -1):

Both are used to store reports in-app. power service.in workspace whatever the reports are exiting others they can't access it like as person workspace and app workspace it shares ab;e workspace and everyone can access it what it has it.